# Move onto next record if previous one is = null

Tags: c#, sql-server, geocoding

I am searching through my database checking addresses and finding the lat/lng using Geocode.
Once I hit a record with a null value it moves to the catch. Any idea how I get this to move to the next record?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source Here";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            try
            {

                reader = new SqlCommand("select PHAddress4, PHAddress5 from  FLC_ProspectHeaderTable", con).ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(reader["PHAddress4"].ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(reader["PHAddress5"].ToString());

                        var address = (reader["PHAddress5"].ToString());
                        var requestUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

                        var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                        var response = request.GetResponse();
                        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

                        var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
                        var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
                        var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
                        var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");
                        Console.WriteLine(lat);
                        Console.WriteLine(lng);


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");

                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.Read();

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: You can filter your command which column values that you don't want as a `null` like `where PHAddress4 is not null` etc.. Or you can check it is `DBNull` or not before you generate their string representation.

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but I think you want to look at DBNull: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Catch the exception inside the loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // examine the exception to see what went wrong
        // if you can't continue, then "throw;"
        // else...
        continue;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Note that the above would be how one would recover from an exception to continue a loop.  *However*, perhaps I misunderstood the question originally.  If the exception can easily and meaningfully be avoided *in the first place* (that is, if it's not really an *exceptional* condition), then that would be preferred.  Consider the adage that one should never use exceptions to control logic flow.

If, logically, you're able to check for this condition before performing the operation which would result in an exception, then the overall structure of the code would look more like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // do something
    if (someCondition)
    {
        // do the rest of the something
    }
    else
        continue;
}
```

(Or you could invert the condition to check for the "continue" case first, that works just as well.  It's up to you what looks cleaner in your code.)

In your particular case, it entirely depends on *what* is causing it to fail.  For example, if one of your variables is `null`, then you can check for that:

```
var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
if (result == null)
    continue;
```

Basically, you need to determine what *can* fail in your code and introduce some logical conditions to recover from that failure.  Ideally any such "continuing" of the loop would be done before any permanent side-effects occur.  In your code it looks like the only permanent side-effects are writing to the console, so I'd recommend putting all of those at the very end of the loop body.  Then as you check your conditions you can `continue;` any time you encounter a continue-able failure state in the logic.  If everything passes, the code would get to the lines which write to the console and then naturally continue.

Comment: Why not just check for null? This code is not only slower but a pain to debug.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson: Perhaps I misunderstood the intent of the question.  I was under the impression that the exception was a given and the OP was looking for a way to recover from it.  Certainly, if the exception can be easily avoided, that would be a preferred approach.  I'll revise...

Answer (score 1):

You could check your columns for null and continue. This is normally considered cleaner than catching an exception, especially if you expect some null values here and there.

Something like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   // Skip row if columns are null
   if (reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("PHAddress4"))) continue;
   if (reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("PHAddress5"))) continue;

   // No nulls, go ahead and read the columns
    Console.WriteLine(reader["PHAddress4"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(reader["PHAddress5"].ToString());
  ...
```